# App Widget update TextView

Tags: android, timer, textview, android-appwidget

I have been following a tutorial to make Android App Widgets, and I was having a little trouble. The tutorial led me to create this code:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int [] appWidgetIds) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 1000);
}

private class MyTime extends TimerTask {

    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    ComponentName thisWidget;
    DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());

    public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, FlipWidget.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, "Time: "+format.format(new Date()));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

but it seems that the run method is never being called, as the TextView never changes. Thanks for your help, I'd love to get a handle on App Widgets.

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you cannot use `Timer`. Your `AppWidgetProvider`, and the `Timer`, will be garbage-collected once `onUpdate()` returns.

Second, please do not update an app widget every second. There is a reason why `android:updatePeriodMillis` has a 30-minute minimum -- pushing updates to app widgets is an expensive operation. Updating one every second would not only force your "update an app widget" code to effectively be resident in memory and running all of the time, but you will also whack the user's battery pretty significantly.

For periodic updates of an app widget, either use `android:updatePeriodMillis` or use `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. Clocks need to be updated every second though, will AlarmManager let me do this battery efficiently?

Comment: @Nick: Do not implement a clock as an app widget. Clocks are a feature of a home screen, or are a feature of some other activity (e.g., an alarm clock app).

Comment: So I do not extend AppWidgetProvider. So how do homescreen widgets that are clocks work, where do I start now?

Comment: NOTE: Once I figure out how to get a widget that updates often enough to be a useful clock, would it be more acceptable to use System.currentTimeMillis() rather than a Java Date()?

Comment: @Nick: "homescreen widgets that are clocks" that update every second are bad for the battery, period. You are welcome to write a normal Android application that has a clock that updates every second, particularly using `postDelayed()` for the timing. You are welcome to write a home screen application that has a clock built in. You are welcome to write an app widget that updates, say, every minute, using `AlarmManager`. There is nothing to prevent you from creating a clock app widget that updates every second -- it's just that you're saying you hate your users.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've seen this sort of answer on plenty of StackOverflow responses. I don't necessarily need the exact second to be displayed, I'm doing a digital-clock style widget, however if updating every minute with AlarmManager won't my clock not update exactly when the minute changes? I don't hate my users, I am working through this process with people like you who understand Android's underpinnings more so that I can learn things like this, no need to get upset.

Comment: @Nick: "however if updating every minute with AlarmManager won't my clock not update exactly when the minute changes?" It is certainly not guaranteed. Android is not a RTOS. It won't be early, but it could easily be late by a second or two (e.g., user playing a game in the foreground hogging the CPU). That's true for any implementation that will look to update in the background. The only way to get closer accuracy is with a foreground activity, and even that is not guaranteed to be real time.

Comment: I was thinking, what if the process starts at 5:32:15, and the AlarmManger updates on a minute basis, wouldn't the clock not change to say 5:33 until 15 seconds after 5:33?

Comment: @Nick: You provide the starting time for the `AlarmManager` recurring alarm. So, you set the starting time to be 5:33:00 and the period to be every minute thereafter. That will get you reasonably close.

Comment: Oh, awesome. Thanks so much for your help. I think I can puzzle it out from here. I'll post a new question if trouble arises, but you've been really helpful.